# Is there a way to protect the folder with password?

Tags: java, android, password-protection

Is there a way to programmatically protect the folder with password in Android ?

Answer (score 3):

> By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user).

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: I still can pull the file from DDMS.

Comment: Works only for non rooted phones. Rooted phones (and the emulators) have super user access.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, No, you cannot.

You could zip the contents of the folder and store it as an Passworded Zip File. That's the closest solution i can think of. ofcourse, the folder won't exist anymore.